# Crystal Report Decimal value to Integer

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2005

In database it is stored in Bigint but when comes tocrystal reports page it displays in decimal format; Value is in database (3), But when comes to crystal reports page becomes (3.00). How to change it?

[image: sample]

but I need it in integer round off like below

```
A | B
7 | 6
```

i'm using visual studio 2005.

there is no number format tab 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the number field on the report.
2. Right-click and format.
3. On the Number tab, click on the Customize button.
4. On the Number tab, set the number of decimal places to 0.

Comment: In the Format Editor there is no Number Format Tab check my post again for updates

Answer (score 0):

1. Select The field
2. Right Click
3. Click on Format Object
4. Click on Number Format
5. Click on Customize
6. On Decimalas Select 1

Click on OK

Comment: In the Format Editor there is no Number Format Tab check my post again for updates

Comment: Number tab appears only for Numerical fields. Check your Database for field definition. Field is definitely not defined as Bigint.  If it is defined as Bigint then goto field explorer click on table name and click Verify Database